# I really need help to understand the nature of Static method

Tags: flutter, dart

When a instance function being declare Static, does that mean that it can't return a new instance of another object?
Aren't the purpose of the Static keyword is to save the memory, does that mean when i call the static member, it had to return for me the EXACT object ?

```
class Provider extends InheritedWidget {
  final  bloc = Bloc();
  bool updateShouldNotify(_) => true;

  Provider({Key key, Widget child}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  static Bloc of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Provider>().bloc;
  }
}

class SignUp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 // This is not the same object
    final bloc = Provider.of<Bloc>(context);
}


class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This is not the same object 
    final bloc = Provider.of<Bloc>(context);
}
```

Comment: Please read: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#class-variables-and-methods

Answer (score 1):

Once function is declared static, that means it is no longer "instance" function, but rather class function.

Declaring function static means that you no longer have access to instance (i.e. this). This is just function aliased by the class it is declared in.

Static function can return anything, including new instances of classes, where it is declared.

Static function will not help you to save memory.

My assumption though (I might be wrong) is that static function is a little bit easier for compiler to compile as it does not take part in polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Everything from Alex above is correct.

I just want to point the most important differences you should no:

1. It is not related to any object, and so it can be called directly from the class.
2. In Java and maybe other languages polymorphic rules no longer work as expected. For this many people do use the Singleton-Pattern, which itself is based on a static function.

Further reading:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_(keyword)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern
- https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-methods-vs-instance-methods-java/

In general you should try doing some own research before asking questions here, and so make questions less random ;)